Java Graphics - Drawing multiple images next to each other creates empty lines | SOLVED
I am trying to draw the map of my game, it has tiles object with x & y location.
The image of the tiles are hold by 1 class, and i resize them once i finished zooming.
I want to draw the images with double precision, in fact i am using the AffineTransform to translate them, and also scaling with double precision.
In the Camera class i have the zoom variable as double.
When the zoom is 0, it seems that everything is okay, but when i move the mouse this bug stil happends. (Because the camera moves based on the distance of the mouse from the center)
I am drawing everything on a panel called GameScreen, i have multiple ScreenPainter classes where i draw different stuff, and then draw everything on that panel.
GameScreen class:
public class GameScreen extends JPanel {

    private static GameScreen INSTANCE;
    private static Graphics2D graphics2D;

    private List<ScreenPainter> painters = new ArrayList<>();

    public GameScreen() {
        INSTANCE = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        for (ScreenPainter painter : painters) painter.paint();
        for (BAText text : new ArrayList<>(TextRegistry.getTexts().values())) {
            if (text != null) text.drawText(graphics2D);
        }

        //if (BlueArchangels.STATE == GameState.PAUSE) MenuRegistry.getExitMenu().paint(graphics);

        graphics2D.dispose();
    }

    public void updatePainters() {
        painters = new ArrayList<>(ScreenPainterManager.getPainters());
    }

    public static GameScreen INSTANCE() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static Graphics2D getGraphics2D() {
        return graphics2D;
    }
}

Method in the MapPainter class
    @Override
    public void paint() {
        if (grids == null) {
            assignValue();
            return;
        }

        double cellWidth = getCellWidth(), cellHeight = getCellHeight();
        boolean zooming = Camera.zooming();

        for (Map.TileGrid tileGrid : grids) {
            int offsetX = tileGrid.getOffsetX(), offsetY = tileGrid.getOffsetY();

            for (Map.Tile tile : tileGrid.getAllTiles()) {
                BufferedImage image = tile.getTileImage();
                if (image == null) continue;

                double width = cellWidth, height = cellHeight;
                double x = width * (tile.x + offsetX), y = height * (-tile.y - offsetY);

                AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();

                // Ground tiles are already at the same size as the cell.
                if (!tile.isGround()) {
                    double w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
                    // Check how many times the cell stays inside the image, to scale it later.
                    double timesX = w / width, timesY = h / height;

                    // Calculate the target size of the tile.
                    width = width * timesX;
                    height = height * timesY;

                    // Scale the size to the target size.
                    transform.scale(width / w, height / h);

                    // Now with the target size, we calculate the exact location to place it in its cell at (x; y).
                    // Otherwise, when scaled it will be placed on another cell and not its original.

                    // Now we correct the position by placing the x coordinate and
                    // the bottom part of the tile in the middle of the cell.
                    x += -(width / 2D) + (cellWidth / 2D);
                    y += -height + (cellHeight / 2D);
                }

                if (Camera.isOutCamera(x, y, width, height)) continue;

                if (zooming) {
                    // If zooming and the tile is ground, scale it to the correct size while waiting for resizing.
                    if (tile.isGround()) {
                        //transform.scale(width / image.getWidth(), height / image.getHeight());
                        x += -(width / 2) + (cellWidth / 2);
                        y += -(height / 2) + (cellHeight / 2);
                    }
                    wasZooming = true;
                } else {
                    // Once the game is no more zooming, update the ground tile sizes and draw them without scaling.
                    if (wasZooming) resizeMapTiles();
                    wasZooming = false;
                }
                transform.translate(Camera.toX(x), Camera.toY(y));

                if (zooming) {
                    // If zooming and the tile is ground, scale it to the correct size while waiting for resizing.
                    if (tile.isGround()) transform.scale(width / image.getWidth(), height / image.getHeight());

                }

                int degrees = tile.getRotation();
                if (degrees != 0) transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), width / 2D, height / 2D);

                ScreenPainter.drawImage(image, transform);
            }
        }
    }


Any idea of why this is happening? Video of the problem
Edit 1
I found the main problem of these lines. (From what i tested)
The problem is drawing at double precision, i edited the zoom varibable to be an integer, and the problem was dramatically reduced, now the problem happen when i try to move, because the location is also at double precision, when i draw with integer position, the problem doesn't show up.
Now the other question is, how do i fix the double precision problem? Is is a rendering problem? Rounding problem? Anyone has ever experienced this?

[Edit] your question and post your solution as an answer.

My account is blocked for 11h....

Hello Pulsi, Basically, we are talking about “painting” pixels, there is no pixel with coordinates 1.5, 2.3, so yes, you must use int.

I finally found the problem, after 3 weeks...
The problem that you can see in the video was caused by the JPanel being opaque (I have no idea why it causes that problem).
To fix this annoying bug just set the JPanel as not opaque.
Best way to fix this
Override the isOpaque method to be sure that it will be always on false:
@Override
public boolean isOpaque() {
    return false;
}

